# Angular 4 Firebase show user information

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to query one object from firebase that meets the uid of the logged in user.
i do it like this.

```
FetchUserData() {
    return this.authState.subscribe(authData => {
        this.db.list(`/users/${authData.uid}`)
     });
}
```

in my nav-bar component i expecting to receive user object from the database.

```
user:FirebaseObjectObservable<User>;

this.user = authService.FetchUserData();
```

so my question is what now?
async pipe is not working. map is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of the service.

```
afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
            //Grab the user uid.
    } else {
        console.log('Meh');
    }
});
```